# Does realloc deallocate before trying to allocate new memory?

Tags: c, realloc

I'm having trouble with my exercise here - I want to know about the realloc function a bit more -

If we send a pointer to the realloc, and it fails to allocate memory [returns null] does the memory that used to be allocated, now deallocated? although we failed?

`ePointer = (Element*)realloc(stack->content, (sizeof(Element) * capacityOfStack(stack) * 2));`

when  `stack->content` being the pointer ofcourse, if we failed now have  `ePointer` as  `NULL`, then  `stack->content` is no longer allocated?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: and would be lovely if someone can possibly answer this as well - If we realloc to a smaller number of bytes, then we will 100% not get a NULL?

Comment: Only if the realloc succeeds.  Same rules as first attempt.

Comment: There is no guarantee in the C standard that reallocing to a smaller number of bytes will succeed (although I would guess that most implementations would not fail such a realloc). For safety, you should check for failure even in this case. On failure, you can just carry on using the old buffer since it is large enough.

Answer (score 3):

From the `man` page for [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc):

```
    For realloc(), the input pointer is still valid if reallocation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

`stack->content` is still valid. If `realloc` fails, it returns NULL, but the old block of memory remains valid, that's the interface.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Answer (score 1):

From `man 3 realloc`

> If `realloc()` fails, the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

Answer (score 0):

`realloc()` does not de-allocate before trying to allocate again. What it does is first try to allocate a new block. If it fails, it returns and the old pointer is still valid. If it succeeds, then it copies the content from the original block into the new block, and then calls `free()` on the original block.